# Common among the uncommon

Tags: pattern, knowledge

What is common among the seemingly uncommmon among the following:

1. One of the types of human blood groups
2. Grading representation in schools
3. Part of alternate representation for Like/ up vote
4. Mother of all numerical operations, well, considered in a way
5. That type of growth usually goes up and right

   ?

Comment: I was thinking of "a positive(+)" but can't seem to meet 4th requirement.

Comment: Good thought process @Firelord, you should have posted your answer !

Comment: Well I'm new here and didn't know one can post partial answers here too. I'll try next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common factor is

> + (the plus sign)

1. Blood type

   > For the gene [A, B, or O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABO_blood_group_system), you can have a positive (+) or negative (-) type.
2. Grading representation

   > For each letter grade (A, B, C, etc.) some schools assign plus or minus for granularity. For example, A+ > A > A- > B+ > B, and so on.
3. Like/upvote

   > An upvote are sometimes referred to as +1 (plus one vote).
4. Operators

   > [Addition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addition) (X + Y) is one of the first mathematical operations that people learn. Subtraction is negative addition, and multiplication is repeated addition.
5. Growth

   > A [monotonic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotonic_function) with a positive rate moves up and right. For example, in the function *y=2x*, the rate is *+2* (positive); and when you visualize the graph, the value of *y* moves up as you move right along the *x* axis.

Comment: Good one @Mike Q, you got it fully correct !

Comment: @Dexter Maybe not, it's easy to find out in an instant...

Answer (score 1):

The pattern is:

> The first 5 letters of the alphabet

1)

> A is a blood group

2)

> B is a grade that is given in schools

3)

> Unsure

4)

> D for differentials/derivatives

5)

> E for exponential graph - which is a graph that is always growing... i.e. up and to the right

Comment: Nice try, @Dexter.  Liked the variants in explaning the clues !